# Does Google Universal Analytics support x-forwarded-for header for ip filters?

Tags: filter, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Does Google Universal Analytics support x-forwarded-for header for ip filters?

I am trying to filter out internal ips but it doesn't seem to work.  The application is sitting behind a proxy, so the client's ip is in the x-forwarded header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323748/google-analytic-measurement-endpoint-is-ignoring-x-forwarded-for-header-any-sol) the measurement protocol (which forms the base for all versions of the Google Analytics tracking) ignores x-forwarded ip headers.

This is solved in serverside implementations as Google has added a parameter `uip` (must be a valid IP, will always be anonymized by setting the last three numbers to 000) to the measurement protocol to send a clients ip. I don't know terribly much about proxy servers, but it might be possible to stitch the parameter into the request instead of using a header field.

Comment: Thanks Eike, I saw craigtadlock's post, but didn't have enough rep to ask about uip.  As you mention it is server-side only, and I have only used the standard tracking code to date.  If I were to implement server-side posting to Google Analytics, would I get rid of the tracking code?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately you would also get rid of all the nice things the js tracking code is doing for you automatically, like technology reports, timings etc., you would have to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested this solution yet, but I'm working on it.

It seems like you should be able to do something like this:

```js
import ua from 'universal-analytics'
import publicIp from 'public-ip'

const user = ua(GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID)

const uip = await publicIp.v4()
user.set('uip', uip)
```

After that, you have set the users IP for all coming events and page views.